# cycript TypeError("undefined is not an object when following tutorial

Tags: ios, cycript

I am attempting to follow this tutorial - http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-8-method-swizzling-using-cycript/#article

Close to the bottom of the article, I am at the part where you type:

```
ViewController.messages['validateLogin'] = function() { return true;}
```

but I don't get the response that the author gets, instead I get a TypeError

```
throw new TypeError("undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ViewController.messages.validateLogin=function(){return 1}')"
```

I am running iOS 9.0.2 and have Cycript 0.9.594

Answer (score 2):

This is because the syntax is changed. messages is no longer valid call in Cycript. Instead use .prototype.

```
ViewController.prototype.isDeviceJailbroken = function () { return false; }
```

Reference:

[image]